# Hit Testing a UIButton located outside bounds of SuperView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, hittest

I am trying to animate this view `ControlsView` up by `touchUpInside` in the `UIButton` which is the caret character inside the white square in the image attached.  When the button is hit, a delegate method is fired an the `controlsView` is animated up.  The problem is that because the `UIButton` is outside of the bounds of `controlsView` it does not receive touch info.

I have thought about this a lot and read up on some potential candidate solutions.  Such as detecting the touch event on a super view by overriding `hitTest:withEvent:`. However, the `UIButton` is actually a subview of `CockPitView` which is a subview of `ControlsView` which is a subview of `MainView`.  MainView, it seems, is the rectangle whose coordinates the `UIButton` would truly lie in.  So would I override `hitTest` there and pass the touch info to `CockPitView`, where I could then have my `Button` trigger its action callback?

Has anyone encountered this or a similar problem and have any advice on how to proceed?

[image: visual reference]

Comment: Actually, my book has a discussion of this along with code for an easy solution: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_hit_testing

Answer (score 3):

You should override `hitTest` in your custom view `CockPitView`

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    if (!self.clipsToBounds && !self.hidden && self.alpha > 0) {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
            CGPoint subPoint = [subview convertPoint:point fromView:self];
            UIView *result = [subview hitTest:subPoint withEvent:event];
            if (result != nil) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

`CockPitView` has to be a subclass of `UIView`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `-pointInside:withEvent:`. In your `button`'s superview, i.e., `ControlsView`, override the method like this:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // self.button is the button outside the bounds of your ControlsView
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.button.bounds, [self convertPoint:point toView:self.button])) {
        return YES;
    }
    return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
}
```

By doing this, your `ControlsView` claims that the points inside the bounds of your button should be treated like the points inside your `ControlsView`.